# Django Queryset: Only return entries where a specific field appears greater than N times

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a model with a user foreignkey and a charfield.

How can I filter a queryset so that only users with > 3 entries are returned in one line?

So something like this (which obviously does not exist yet):

```
Post.objects.filter(user__appears__gte=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: updated answer after understanding question

Not the best solution but you can loop for each user in the User object and then check the number of counts it appears in the Post object, if greater than 2 return those Post objects.

```
all_posts = Post.objects.none()
all_users = User.objects.all()

for user in all_users:
    user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user)
    if user_posts.count() > 2:
        all_posts = all_posts | user_posts
```

Comment: Yes, I want to return all entries where the user appears more than twice.

Comment: Do you know the specific user you are filtering for?

Comment: No, it should return all posts for users as long as the user has posted twice.

Comment: @aroooo did this work? If so can you kindly accept the answer so this question can be closed. If not, what errors did you get?